# Work with the user after login, C# Identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have the following class that defines a user:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{

    public int UserType { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("true")]
    public bool NewUser { get; set; }
}
```

Im using the following code In my AuthController to sign in a user:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LogIn(LogInModel model)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            var user = await userManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignIn(user);
                return Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(model.ReturnUrl));
            }

            // user authN failed
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email or password");
            return View();
        }
```

Here Is my controller that handels everything when the user Is logged In:

```
   [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> userManager;

        public HomeController()
       : this(Startup.UserManagerFactory.Invoke())
        {
        }

        public HomeController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
        }

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            var authManager = ctx.Authentication;

            //var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
            //Kolla om det är new user
            //Om det är new user, visa "setup"-sida där man kan konfa sitt konto
            //Annars renderar vi default
            return View();
        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && userManager != null)
            {
                userManager.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

My question Is: How do I work with the logged in user? How can I access the user when he/she has logged In? Can I use the AppUser-class here to represent the user who Is logged In?

The AppUser Is a description Of the corresponding user table in the database, so how can I access all this properties that belongs to the logged in user? Can I use some information from the var `ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();`?

In PHP for example, you are using the session_id that represents the user. But how do you do It here in C# with Identity?

Comment: The username is usually stored in `User.Identity.Name`. You can use that to look up the user.

Comment: @Sam: In GwtOwinContext or what?

Comment: @Sam, no, `User` is a property on the `Controller` class. So inside your controller action you could use `User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: should I use the Name to work with, Instead of the ID of the user?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - There was no Razor code in his examples and in MVC we are strongly encouraged to load the models in controllers, so I assumed `User.Identity.Name` was all he needed based on his description. As mentioned in the accepted answer, if you need it from the Razor view, you'll need to access the user via the context.

Comment: @Bryan - There is an index on the username so performance should be okay, but if you would rather use the id, include the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` namespace and then you can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()` to get the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve the user authenticated in HttpRequest, this way in any controller HttpContext.Current.User.Identity

I recommend that you verified if you request is authenticated this way HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

In Asp.Net Mvc in controller can you retrieve context with the class ViewContex

I hope I've helped

Comment: Which ViewContext do you mean?

Comment: ViewContext contains all request information. Can you look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Thank you. But shouid I use the Name to work with, Instead of the ID of the user?

Comment: As you inherited the IdentyUser you can input the userid in this class and when you receive HttpContext.Current.User.Identity you would be receiving your class, this way you cast Identity to your class to access userid. .Net Identiy don't use id because this way is possible use a lot of kind identification, where the people use only email as key.

Comment: In User.Identity there is a method getuserid() where you can override to return your ID.